Adding the pdf to an existing PDF using pdf-lib nodejs
I have an existing file in ./print/print.pdf. And new pdf bytes called const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
I want to add the pdfBytes to print.pdf and I've been trying to do that using pdf-lib on Node.js
const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();

const pdfA = await PDFDocument.load(fs.readFileSync(`./print/print.pdf`));
const pdfB = pdfBytes;

const copiedPagesA = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdfA, pdfA.getPageIndices());
copiedPagesA.forEach((page) => mergedPdf.addPage(page));

const copiedPagesB = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdfB, pdfB.getPageIndices());
copiedPagesB.forEach((page) => mergedPdf.addPage(page));

await mergedPdf.save();

I've found this solution on Github and I was trying hard to make it work. But, I am getting
error.
What am I missing here? I want to put them together as one and override the name print.pdf in the same directory.

The .save() method returns a UInt8Array, so you can't use that directly as a PDF document in subsequent calls.
